# How to transform Cloudify 2.7 recipe into Cloudify 3.1 Blueprint

Tags: groovy, yaml, cloudify

I am currently using Cloudify 2.7 and I have developed a lot of recipes. Is it possible to transform Cloudify 2.7 recipe into Cloudify 3.x Blueprint?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! The first part of your question is very specific and suits the rules of questions here. The second part is very opinion based - some people would say you should definitely learn YAML as its the Markup Language to beat all markup languages, others would say it's just Yet another. Please read ["how to ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid these - I'll suggest an edit to your post.  Also - [signoffs (however polite / well intentioned) are discouraged here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

Comment: Thank you Richard for pointing out my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

There's no automatic way of converting recipes into Cloudify 3 TOSCA blueprints. But there a few things that should make it easier:

- The cloudify [script plugin](http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.1/plugin-script.html) support any scripting language so you can use Groovy or shell for that matter. You will need to remove the calls to the 2.7 context object and use the [cloudify 3 ctx utility](http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.1/plugin-script.html#context-proxy).
- Life cycle events are quite similar, with the default life cycle interface of Cloudify 3. You can check out the [hello world example](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-hello-world-example/blob/3.1/hello-world/blueprint.yaml#L62-L65) or the [nodecellar one](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-hello-world-example/blob/3.1/hello-world/blueprint.yaml#L62-L65) for a more details.

HTH
Uri

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog entry about a specific porting effort: http://blog.gigaspaces.com/migrating-xap-from-cloudify-2-7-to-cloudify-3/.  Note that in the article, some of the information about script porting is out of date. The new script plugin makes things considerable easier (http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.1/plugin-script.html).  For your recipes that use non-groovy scripting, you can salvage the vast majority of that work.  Scripts written in groovy will need to be rewritten, preferably in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few additions to Uri's answer :

A blueprint enables you to define your topology and orchestration plans.

It contains : Plugin declarations, Inputs and Outputs , Types, Nodes and Relationships, Intrinsic functions , Workflows and Policies

In general, every entity is a node in the Cloudify blueprints :

A few examples of nodes:  Compute resource, Application module,network,security group,DB, Web server.

In the blueprint, you can also define relationships between nodes.

Currently there are three relationships types:

```
* depends_on – which is the base type
* contained_in – a component is hosted / contained / deployed within another component
* connected_to – a component needs to establish a connection to another and therefore this needs to be configured
```

Example :

A Web server is contained in VM#1 and also connected to a Database which is contained in VM#2 (or in VM#1).

Relationships, the same as nodes, can be extended and derive from another relationship.
Examples :

HTH, 
Tamir.